# Effects in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to put some effect to my screen, when it navigates to other page.
When i click a button in the first page it should navigate to second page.
i want some effect when navigate to second page, can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

check out the [fl.transitions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/package-detail.html) package in the ActionScript documentation.  there are some ready-made transitions you can use (Fade, Fly, Wipe, etc.) or you can create your own with the Tween class.